# Jquery exstract all posible links from full text and convert to href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I search solution but i dont find right solution.

I have text

```
<div  class="text">
Hello world! I like google.com and love https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask but i
like to www.wikipedia.com and http://example.com or http://www.example.com
and even https://www.example.com
</div>
```

What i need to  do

```
<script>
$(".text") -- OR -- function(){

//CONVERT LINKS 
google.com  ==> <a href="google.com">Link</a>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask  ==> <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">Link</a>
www.wikipedia.com  ==> <a href="www.wikipedia.com">Link</a>
http://example.com  ==> <a href="http://example.com ">Link</a>
http://www.example.com  ==> <a href="http://www.example.com">Link</a>
https://www.example.com ==> <a href="https://www.example.com">Link</a>

});
</script>
```

Thanks for help! Possible duplicate!

Comment: Thanks for help! Possible duplicate! ---- Huh?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: @CertainPerformance is right, but I'll throw you a bone anyway: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: What are your requirements?  Do you need to roll your own or are you allowed to use a 3rd party plugin?  If so, [Linkify](https://soapbox.github.io/linkifyjs/) should work well for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to roll your own, I'd keep it simple and use an already built and tested 3rd party plugin like [Linkify](https://soapbox.github.io/linkifyjs/).

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $( "#linkifyMe").click(function() {
    $('.text').linkify();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-linkify/2.1.8/linkify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-linkify/2.1.8/linkify-jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="text">
Hello world! I like google.com and love https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask but i
like to www.wikipedia.com and http://example.com or http://www.example.com
and even https://www.example.com
</div>

<p>
  <button id="linkifyMe">Click to Linkify</button>
</p>
```